# Bad Bind for Sinatra App on Heroku

Tags: heroku, sinatra

My goal here is to see if I'm missing something obvious with regard to deploying a small Sinatra application to Heroku and diagnosing why a port error comes up.

I am deploying a fairly simple application to Heroku. The application code is here:

https://github.com/jnyman/symbiont-app

The application itself is:

http://symbiont-app.herokuapp.com/

It's a really simple test application. However, when I deploy to Heroku, I get an application error. The error reported in the logs is:

```
    Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 3000, should be 49668 (see environment variable PORT)
    heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
    heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

This is what I have in my Procfile:

```
    web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

My understanding from what I have investigated is that not having that "-p $PORT" was the most likely cause of the error I am seeing. But I clearly have that line in place. Further, everything works fine in a local environment, when I run:

```
    bundle exec rackup config.ru
```

I can test my application without issue. The same applies when I use:

```
    foreman start
```

Again, application works just fine. I deploy to heroku with the standard command:

```
    git push heroku master
```

There were no errors during this process. Last part of the update was:

```
    -----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> web
       Default types for Ruby/Rack -> console, rake
    -----> Compiled slug size: 15.7MB
    -----> Launching... done, v12
       http://symbiont-app.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

So works locally; only has an error when deploying to Heroku. The only error seems to be about a port. What I can't find is much information that helps me figure out how to diagnose what I'm seeing. I feel like I might be missing something obvious with this port issue, but I don't know what that is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it's appropriate to add a comment to my own question like this, but I did notice something. In going back through the logs in Heroku, it seems that the port is always trying to use 3000. I did a search through my entire application and there is nowhere that I specify that number at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get an answer of sorts to this. Essentially what it comes down to is that "sometimes" when deploying to Heroku, you can run into this "port conflict" issue and there is very little you can do about it save to delete your app from Heroku, recreate the app, and then redeploy.

Just to give some context, with the above problem, I could get nothing to work. So I tried the nuclear option -- I got rid of just about all of my files, except for a static HTML file and a simple route. Even when redeploying with just that, my app would still have the port conflict.

So I deleted my Heroku app, recreated it and then repushed my full version: sure enough, everything worked. Not much of an answer I suppose, but I can't argue with the evidence.